# Display success message after sql query in the same page as form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit

I have submit form, and I wanna to make simple success message after submit (example: I submited this form, and I wanna to auto-redirect to all rows, and then above all rows will be my success message).

```
   <?php
        //Gauname duomenis iš formos
        $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
        $author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
        $sport = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sport']);
        $event = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event']);
        $pick = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pick']);
        $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);


        //Vykdome užklausa
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (date, author, event, sport, pick, status) VALUES ('$date', '$author', '$event', '$sport', '$pick', '$status')";

        //Gauname atsakyma
        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo "Sekimngai iterpta <br /> ";
        } else {
            echo "Ivyko klaida" . mysql_error();
        }
?>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h2 class="sub-header">Statymo pridėjimas</h2>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="control-label col-xs-2">Data</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Autorius</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="event" class="control-label col-xs-2">Įvykis</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event" name="event">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sport" class="control-label col-xs-2">Sportas</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <select name="sport" id="sport" class="form-control">
                <option value="/darbas/images/football.png">Futbolas</option>
                <option value="/darbas/images/basketball.png">Krepšinis</option>
                <option value="/darbas/images/tennis.png">Tenisas</option>
                <option value="/darbas/images/hockey.png">Ledo ritulys</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pick" class="control-label col-xs-2">Pasirinkimas</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pick" name="pick">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="status" class="control-label col-xs-2">Statusas</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
                <option value="Laukiama">Laukiama</option>
                <option value="Laimėta">Laimėta</option>
                <option value="Pralaimėta">Pralaimėta</option>
                <option value="Grąžinta">Grąžinta</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pridėti statymą">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1) MySQL is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. 2) what have you tried? 3) I would include a IF statement to prevent the page from trying to INPUT data every time the page loads.